# Dynamically shrink SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, scaling, skspritenode

Title sort of explains it all. I have a SKSpriteNode, called bar. It's assigned an image that is a red longways rectangle. I want it to slowly decrease in length over an interval, while keeping the width the same. In other words, imagine it sort of folding in on itself vertically.

Comment: well, change its scale or size properties, ie by using appropriate skactions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SKActions` to do that. `SKAction.scaleYTo` function can be use to scale the height of the sprite. The `anchor point` can be shifted to one edge to prevent the rectangle from scaling towards the middle.

```
var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redBar.png")
sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
sprite.position = CGPointMake(95, 100)
self.addChild(sprite)

let duration = 10.0
let finalHeightScale:CGFloat = 0.0
let scaleHeightAction = SKAction.scaleYTo(finalHeightScale, duration: duration)


sprite.runAction(scaleHeightAction, completion: { () -> Void in
    println("Height is zero")
})
```

Comment: I tried using SKActions and scaling, but that just ends up crashing my program. I think it is being invoked infinitely or something? Or it is stuck on that action and waits infinitely.